# I can't access Bitnami Redmine's Subversion

Tags: svn, redmine, bitnami

I installed Bitnami Redmine in Windows. It installs a built-in Subversion.

But I can't get to access it and neither can find svnadmin commands I need.

If I run for example `svnadmin create project1`, it just closes without printing any text. I suppose the project was created but I don't know what its URL is so that I can use Tortoise to checkout.

Also, what command do I use to see existing projects? And how can I see their proper URL?

Comodo says svnserve.exe is running and listening on port 3691.

Sorry for these basic questions. I was used to VisualSVN, but it has no support for svn:// protocol and I can't get Redmine to checkout from it using either http:// or file:///

Answer (score 1):

BitNami Redmine ships a Subversion server already configured. It is optional, you can use it or you can use your own Subversion repository. There is more info about how to create the Subversion repository at http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Subversion#How_to_start_the_Subversion_server.3a_svnserver.3f. You can also configure Apache to show this repository through http.